# Create object of class that implements Parcelable

Tags: android, parcelable

How do you actually create an object of a class that implements Parcelable? There are lots of examples online that shows exactly what the class should look like, but I can't seem to find something on how to create the object.

If I have a class that implements Parcelable, and the contructor looks like this:

```
public class ResultForTeam implements Parcelable
{

    String playerA, playerB, teamA, teamB, scores;
    int playerA_games, playerB_games;


    public ResultForTeam(Parcel in) 
    {
        this.playerA = in.readString();
        this.playerB = in.readString();
        this.teamA = in.readString();
        this.teamB = in.readString();
        this.scores = in.readString();
        this.playerA_games = in.readInt();
        this.playerB_games = in.readInt();
    }
```

how do I then make an object of this class somewhere else in my code?
It used to be like this before I implemented Parcelable.

```
ResultForTeam newResult = new ResultForTeam(playerA, playerB, teamA, teamB, scores, playerA_games, playerB_games);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your old constructor and this overloaded one. You'll need to also implement the `describeContents()` and `writeToParcel()` methods. Don't forget to write the static `CREATOR` field as well. You will then be able to use the class as you always have and use it with a `Parcel`.

Comment: Thanx @Larry! I think I missed somewhere that I had to have 2 constructors for my class. No I can just declare the object like before and pass it around different activities with ArrayList and results = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("results");